# less than conditional not working for floats

Tags: javascript, jquery

heres my jquery/javascript code:

```
amount_sale = parseFloat($('#p_sale span').html()).toFixed(2);
amount_cash = parseFloat($('#p_cash span').html()).toFixed(2);

if (amount_cash < amount_sale)
{
    alert('Cash amount must be greater than or equal to sale amount');
    return;
}
```

lets say that the html is as follows:

```
<p id="p_sale">Sale: <span>10.00</span></p>
<p id="p_cash">Cash: <span>20.00</span></p>
```

for whatever reason, even if the contents within the p_cash span is greater than the contents within the p_sale span, i still get the alert.

i don't get it.

Comment: That should work fine. Here's a fiddle showing it working: http://jsfiddle.net/r3ELy/

Comment: try `alert('Cash amount (' + amount_cash + ') must be greater than or equal to sale amount (' + amount_sale + ')');` and see what the output is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`toFixed` converts the number to a fixed string. Before it, you just have a number, without precision. I'm sure you want:

```
amount_sale = parseFloat($('#p_sale span').html()).toFixed(2);
amount_cash = parseFloat($('#p_cash span').html()).toFixed(2);

if (amount_cash < amount_sale)
{
    alert('Cash amount must be greater than or equal to sale amount');
    return;
}
```

Normally, that would still work with values like `10.00` and `20.00` - but definitely not with `128.50` and `3.14`.

Comment: minitech: I like the in-code strikethrough. Hope you don't mind I added some syntax coloring.